# InputStream read is blocked while reading BLOB from Oracle column through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, blob, java-6

While trying to read from an InputStream obtained from a BLOB like below code, the InputStream goes to indefinite wait state.

I set this data from a web application running on Jboss app server and read/write works absolutely fine, problem is while running a standalone java code using plain JDBC.

Environment is JDK6, Oracle 10g.

```
    ResultSet rs = this.stmt.executeQuery();
    log.println("ResultSetType: " + (rs != null ? rs.getClass() : null));
    while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            . . . // read other columns
            Blob savedBlob = rs.getBlob("PERSISTENCE_BLOB");

            long len = savedBlob.length();
            log.println("Going to read bytes..." + len);
            InputStream is  = savedBlob.getBinaryStream();
            log.println("IS Received...");
            log.println("Available : " + is.available());
            ObjectInputStream oip = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            Object obj = oip.readObject();
            oip.close();
            is.close();

            savedBlob.free();
. . .
```

Output is as Below...

```
ResultSetType: class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl
RowID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  // Row is selected and printed properly
Going to read bytes...6022
IS Received...
Available : 0
```

But if i try to read as below in chucks.. it works fine, which i don't want as i am reading a serialized object and want to have ObjectInputStream opend from InputStream.

```
. . .    
ResultSet rs = this.stmt.executeQuery();
log.println("ResultSetType: " + (rs != null ? rs.getClass() : null));
while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
   . . .    
   Blob savedBlob = rs.getBlob("PERSISTENCE_BLOB");
   long len = savedBlob.length();
   int start = 1;
   int totalBytesRead = 0;
   int buffSize = 2048;
   byte[] byteBuff = null;

   log.println("Going to read bytes..." + len);
   do {
      byteBuff = new byte[buffSize];
      byteBuff = savedBlob.getBytes(start, buffSize);
      totalBytesRead += buffSize;
      log.println(start + "," + buffSize + " #BLOB bytes: " + new String(byteBuff));
      start += buffSize;

       . . . 

   } while (. . . );
 log.println("Total Bytes: " + totalBytesRead);
```

Output:

```
ResultSetType: class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl
Going to read bytes...6022
1,2048 #BLOB bytes: //......bytes data..........
.....
Total Bytes: 6022
```

Answer (score 1):

[`InputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) doesn't indicate how much you can read, it indicates how much it can return to you (eg from a buffer), without going into a - potentially - blocking read operation.

The Javadoc also indicates:

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

and

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

So instead of using `available()` as any sort of indication, just read it (which clearly works as indicated by your other code).

Comment: Thanks Mark, but i want to use InputStream rather than reading in byte chunks. As i mention same code works under Jboss, but not when using JDBC in a standalone java application.

Comment: You should be able use the `InputStream` just fine, that was my point. And otherwise you really need to demonstrate how the InputStream fails, because nothing in your post actually indicates that it fails, just a misinterpretation of the meaning of `available()`.

Comment: Ok. so when i run the app as Java application from Eclipse or run it from a command line, it just hangs there and does nothing after last log line of Available... I have to manually terminate it.

Comment: Then post what your application does after printing the value of available. Your current code does not show the problem.

Comment: Updated code.. it tries to open ObjectInputStream and read object. It hangs right after printing log Available (it's there for just debug purpose only)